# TypeScript 5.2.2 + Redis 4.6.8 Problem (Argument of type...)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, redis

I'm applying to a start up looking to sell services and products in the metaverse. They sent me a challenge in which I have to:

1. Create a microservice where a client can connect via Socket.io
2. When connecting the user should see the available rooms and, when entering any room, this should return the x, y, z position of all available coins.

etc...

Here I store the rooms with the coins in Redis

```
const loadRoom = async () => {
  await client.connect();

  const newRoom: Room = {
    id: 0,
    space: generateRandomSpaceWithoutNulls()
  };

  printRoom(newRoom);

  client.set("room", JSON.stringify(newRoom));
};
```

This is the function that generates the error below

```
app.get('/room', async (req, res) => {
    client.get('room', (err: Error | null, reply: string | null) => {
      if (reply !== null) {`your text`
        return res.json(JSON.parse(reply));
      }
    });
  });`
```

The problem I have is:

```
Argument of type '["room", (err: Error | null, reply: string | null) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number> | undefined]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[key: RedisCommandArgument] | [options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: RedisCommandArgument]'.
  Type '["room", (err: Error | null, reply: string | null) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number> | undefined]' is not assignable to type '[options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: RedisCommandArgument]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [symbol]: true; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old syntax for Node Redis 3.x which didn't support Promises. This was changed with Node Redis 4.x which is what you get if you `npm install redis`.

Try this syntax instead:

```js
await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
```